# How do I connect to an OpenDataSet from Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, opendata

From Azure Storage Explorer I can connect to the OpenWeatherData container trivially as it's a public url:

[image]

From the Azure Data Factory I can not find any documentation on how to connect to a public blob container

The closest I could get is to connect the following way with a dummy token:

[image]

When I attempt to create a dataset though I get a 404 error:

[image]

I also get a 404 error when I attempt to browser:

[image]

So what is the proper approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The things you do are right.

This error causes by the file path you typed is wrong.

> When I attempt to create a dataset though I get a 404 error:

This is because you want to browse from the root path, but it is not public.

> I also get a 404 error when I attempt to browser:

Two ways to solve this error:

1.Since your 'gfsweatherdatacontaine' is public, you can browse from this path. So just type your container name and click 'From specified path'.

[image]

2.Generate SAS from blob, and copy SAS Token form blob storage to link service in ADF.

I think the first way is better for you.